# Use child component instance as a prop in angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, components, parent-child

I've created a `basicModalComponent`, which is taking care of basic actions, like closing, submitting, displaying a header and a footer. It's working well to put simple messages in the body of my modal.

But I'd love to be able to pass a child-component to manage my body, something like this:

```
this.modal = await this.modalController.create({
  component: BasicModalComponent,
  componentProps: {
    title: `Share!`,
    body: ChildContentViewComponent,
    bodyProps: {... some data here},
    // body: new ChildContentViewComponent({some data here}),
    confirm: this.onConfirmDeleteAction,
    cancelButton: true
  }
});
```

which would take care of some more complex logic.

For now, this is how the body is displayed in my `basicModalComponent`

```
<p class="modal-body text-center scrollable scrollbar-hidden">
  {{body}}
</p>
```

It was working well with string-text obviously, but not now that I want to put a child component here.

Here the result:

[image]

And if possible w/ data from the parent during the instantiation

But I don't know if it's possible or a good pattern. 
I presume it's possible since this is what the `modalController` is doing actually w/ my `BasicModalComponent` but I'm still not sure about the pattern. I've looked at inheritance and composition, but didn't manage to make it work either.

Would you have any ideas / tips? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please create working instance of your code in stackblitz ?

Comment: Hi @Prince. I've actually answered back to me w/  what I've found. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, So I figured it out, using the [dynamic component loading](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader)

I've added this into my `BasicModalCompoment`

```js
@ViewChild('modalcomponent', {read: ViewContainerRef}) modalBodyComponent: ViewContainerRef;

ngAfterViewInit() { 
  if(this.isBodyAComponent()) {
    const componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(this.body);
    this.modalBodyComponent.clear();
    const componentRef = this.modalBodyComponent.createComponent(componentFactory);

    // settings data to my child Component
    setTimeout(() => {
      (<any>componentRef.instance) = Object.assign((<any>componentRef.instance), this.bodyProps);
    })
  }
}
```

So, I'm able to pass a component as a body of my modal, as well as a string.

```js
this.modal = await this.modalController.create({
  component: BasicModalComponent,
  componentProps: {
    title: `Share!`,
    body: ChildContentViewComponent,
    bodyProps: {
      url: this.url
    }
  }
});
```

In my `ChildContentViewComponent`, I can access my params, as `url` in  that example

Thanks for your time.

Comment: You can use the `*ngComponentOutlet` structural directive too.

Comment: Im not sure I know that yet - Im gonna have a look. Would you have more info on this ?

Comment: https://pasteboard.co/J2PYQ6m.png
https://pasteboard.co/J2PZ5UM.png

Comment: @Anarno how do you pas inputs with this directive?

Comment: This is the drawback of this solution, has some options but is limited.
https://angular.io/api/common/NgComponentOutlet
See here.

Answer (score 5):

This is well explained on [ionic framework site](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/api/components/modal/ModalController/)

```
// Create instance with ProfileComponent as child component
let profileModal = this.modalCtrl.create(ProfileComponent , { userId: 8675309 });
profileModal.present();
```

Comment: My problem was a bit more complex than that. I wanted  to create a modal with a way to be able to pass a dynamic component  as a props. I've answered to this post. so you can see what I've done. Thanks for your time.

Comment: I think you don't have to add your code in that. But if that solved your problem, its good. Enjoy

Comment: What do you mean ?

Comment: What I mean is in above code ProfileComponent , { userId: 8675309 }, Profile component is dynamic component and {userId: 8675309} is that component props. So why this new code?

Comment: Yes - so, I have my `BasicModalComponent` which is taking care of Header/Body/Footer already. And some props are passed in for that. Then I wanted my body to be a component as well. So I can have my own logic in it. without duplicating the header/footer logic & style.

Comment: Okay. that makes more sense.